# How to render a simple JSP page in CQ?

Tags: aem, sling

We have deployed an AngularJS app to CQ5. At the moment, the views for this app are just static HTML files and stored underneath, say, `/apps/myapp/views/`:

- `/apps/myapp/views/list.html`
- `/apps/myapp/views/view.html`
- etc.

Angular then sends AJAX requests to the server and loads and renders these views as needed.

We want to add some dynamic content to these pages. For example:

```
<% if (isGordonFreeman()) { %>
    <button>Launch the Hadron Collider!</button>
<% } %>
```

How can this be done in CQ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot render a JSP directly in CQ5 as Sling renders only the content/resource and not the scripts.

As a quix fix you can create an `nt:unstructured` node with the `sling:resourceType` property set to the path of the jsp (something like below)

```
list: {
    sling:resourceType: "/apps/myapp/views/list.jsp",
    jcr:primaryType: "nt:unstructured"
},
view: {
    sling:resourceType: "/apps/myapp/views/view.jsp",
    jcr:primaryType: "nt:unstructured"
}
```

and then call these paths in your AJAX requests.

But then, it is not recommended to point directly to scripts, as @BertrandDelacretaz rightly points out. Instead you can have components that can service your requests. If there are too many components to create then you can have a single component service your requests with the help of [selectors](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/developing/sling_cheatsheet.html).

For e.g., your component structure can be like the one shown below.

```
/apps/myapp/views
    |_ list.jsp
    |_ view.jsp
    |_ anythingelse.jsp
```

And the resource( say `/content/myapp/views`) will now have the `sling:resourceType` as `/apps/myapp/views`.
And your AJAX requests would be

```
/content/myapp/views.list.html
/content/myapp/views.view.html
/content/myapp/views.anythingelse.html
```

Comment: Pointing directly to scripts like that is not recommended, I would use sling:resourceType=myapp/views for the /apps/myapp/views/views.jsp script and sling:resourceType=myapp/list form the /apps/myapp/list/list.jsp script.

Comment: @BertrandDelacretaz Yes, it is not recommended. This was just a quick fix provided. Will update the answer accordingly.